# Using all input controls for use in one report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have a report that uses a query of input controls. It is a drop-down menu of specific ID's (ie. 28, 13, 30...) I want to know if it is possible to have my report go through each of these parameters and populate the report one page at a time for each of them.

Here is an example of the different parameters I want the report to loop through:
 [image: Here is an example of the different parameters I want the report to loop through]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create a page for all Partner IDs? Or just for the Partner IDs that a user selects? Either is possible.

Using all Partner IDs is probably easier. Modify your report query which probably has something like `WHERE partner_id = $P{partnerID}`. Remove the where clause. Add grouping and sorting to the query to group on partner id. Each group can start on a new page. And now you don't need a parameter at all.

If you want the user to select the Partner IDs, then you need to use a multi-select input control rather than the single-select input control you're using now. Update your query to use something like this: `WHERE $X{IN, partner_id, partnerID}`. Add grouping and sorting as above.

Comment: While this is correct I was wondering if it is possible to have jasperreports automatically run down the list of input controls instead of having to alter my sql queries.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're saying you have a report that gets the information one Partner. Then you want JRS to intelligently dynamically update both your query and report structure to create something new that creates a new group to support a new multi-page report. That would be ambitious. I think you'll have to update the question (or maybe ask a new one) to make it clearer what would be automated.